# Fastest way to get elements from a numpy array and create a new numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have `numpy` array called `data` of dimensions `150x4`
I want to create a new `numpy` array called `mean` of dimensions `3x4` by choosing random elements from `data`.

My current implementation is:

```
    cols = (data.shape[1])
    K=3
    mean = np.zeros((K,cols))
    for row in range(K):
        index = np.random.randint(data.shape[0])
        for col in range(cols):
            mean[row][col] = data[index][col]
```

Is there a faster way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the number of random integers in `numpy.randint` (third argument). Also, you should be familiar with `numpy.array`'s index notations. Here, you can access all the elements in one row by `:` specifier.

```
mean = data[np.random.randint(0,len(data),3),:]
```